# How can I vertically align subfigures of different size without affecting subcaptions?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subcaption

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{mypicture.png}
     \caption{Caption 1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\textwidth}
      \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{mypicture.png}
     \caption{Caption 2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How could I, without moving downward figure 2, align the two captions to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `savebox` for this kind of thing - the idea is to measure the height of the largest figure, and then use the dimensions of that box in the next figure:

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \usebox{\mybox}
        \caption{Caption 1}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \vbox to \ht\mybox{%
            \vfill
            \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}
            \vfill
        }
        \caption{Caption 2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If "Caption 2", for example, spans two or more lines, the alignment will be lost.

Comment: To get a more general solution you can use `\subcaptionbox` as in `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox{\mybox}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=4cm]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Some text and some more text and some more text}[.48\linewidth]{\usebox{\mybox}}\hfill%
\subcaptionbox{Some text }[.48\linewidth]{%
  \hsize=.48\linewidth\vbox to \ht\mybox{%
  \vfill
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-b}
  \vfill
  }%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor formatting of the code in my previous comment, the `%` characters are there in the "real" version to suppress blank spaces at the end of the lines.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks for the details :) I'll incorporate them into my answer :)