# How can I align two captions?

Tags: floats, equations, captions

I have a figure and an equation side by side.  The code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{cycle}
\caption{The opsin cycle.  Clearly denoted are the parameters of the resistive model}
\label{fig:sfig1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\[S+E  \xrightleftharpoons[k_{IS}]{k_{SI}}  I \cdot E \xrightleftharpoons[k_{PI}]{k_{IP}}   P+E\]
\caption{Reaction scheme for enzymatic model}
\label{fig:sfig2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Basis for the restive and enzymatic models, respectively.}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces [image]

How can I make it so that the captions align, but the  figures stay aligned as they are?

Comment: Which package are you using for your `subfigure`s? If it's [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), then it's [obsolete](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764).

Comment: @Werner it's `subcaption` (notice the `subfigure` *environment* not command).

Comment: Here could be the answer,  http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175201/34618

Comment: Note that the answer provided in the linked thread does not fix the problem with multi-line captions, whereas my latest edit does fix this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This assumes that you are using the `subcaption` package, however, without a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) I do not know which package you are using.

**Edit2:** Sorry for misreading the question, here comes the proper solution:

**Edit3:** Now it works for captions with different number of lines.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \newlength{\MyHeight}
    \settoheight{\MyHeight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[b][\MyHeight][c]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enimad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \newlength{\MyOtherHeight}
    \settoheight{\MyOtherHeight}{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[b][\MyOtherHeight][c]{0.49\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Example]

Comment: This does not keep the figures aligned as they are as desired by the OP.

Comment: No; this also changes the vertical alignment of the objects, and the OP specifically requested "so that the captions align, but the figures stay aligned as they are".

Comment: this approach can be salvaged by setting the formula centered vertically in a minipage the same height as the graphic.

Comment: Add more lines to the second caption and the alignment will be lost.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Fixed.